# Alternative Windows NTFS check tool when CHKDSK doesn't finish?

Tags: ntfs

Occasionally when I run CHKDSK on an NTFS partition, it never finishes. The progress bar reaches the apparent end, but it never completes. Note that in these cases, I'm never scanning for bad sectors. I just need a tool to look for the same kind of housekeeping and consistency flaws that CHKDSK looks for and corrects.

I've found and read the answers here for many similar requests for CHKDSK alternatives, but the suggested answers all seem to involve bad sectors or the like, which is not my problem. I've tried EaseUS Partition Master Free, but it relies on CHKDSK.

A commentor elsewhere replied that I needed to find out why CHKDSK doesn't finish in these circumstances. But how can I ever learn *that* without an alternative NTFS file checker that *does* complete and reports any problems it encountered?

So, does anyone know of any third-party CHKDSK alternatives for NTFS partitions just for the kind of problems I'm having? I use both Windows 7 Pro and Windows 10 Pro.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm embarrassed to report that I've already found one that looks good: Check Disk, which can be found here: [Dirk Paehl's Freeware Site](http://www.paehl.de).

I've run it and it worked fine, but it produces messages so similar to Microsoft's that I'm not quite ready to put my full trust in it.  If I run into another situation where the official CHKDSK fails to complete, I'll try this and report back here.